# Evaluate the limit by using epsilon-M approach.

Tags: real-analysis

[image: Can anyone help me please? Don't know where to start since the numerator looks complicated. Thanks!]

Can anyone help me please? Don't know where to start since the numerator looks complicated. Thanks!

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1825641/prove-ex-ey-leq-e-x-y-for-x-belonging-to-0-1

Answer (score 2):

In the case $x=y$ there is nothing to prove. Thus suppose $x>y$ wlog. Then the mean value theorem shows
$$ 
\frac{e^x-e^y}{x-y}=e^\xi\leq e
$$
for some $\xi\in(0,1)$. This proves the claim.

Your task is now to check whether the mean value theorem was applicable at all.